# Adjoint of forgetful functor between category of vector spaces and category of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, vector-spaces, abelian-groups

I've just found out about the [forgetful functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetful_functor) between the [category of vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_vector_spaces) and the [category of abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_abelian_groups). It maps a vector space to it's additive abelian group.

My question is, is there an [adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) of this forgetful functor, and if so what is it?

If we considered the forgetful functor between the category of vector spaces and the category of sets that forgets all structure, I think the adjoint functor would take a set and create a generic [free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object) vector space generated by the elements of the set.

However, when forgetting only to the level of an abelian group, there still retains some additional structure, so I don't think it's that simple. For example, just by looking at the additive group, you know $v$ and $v+v$ are related by the scalar multiplication $v+v=2v$. Similarly, one could deduce that rational combinations like $6v$ and $9v$ are related through multiplication, since there would exist an element $3v$ that can be added to itself several times to create both. On the other hand, just by looking at the additive structure, I think there is no way to tell that $v$ and $\pi v$ were once related since $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: This is a special case of the tensor–hom adjunction, because the forgetful functor isomorphic to $\textrm{Hom}_k(k, -)$. It's worth noting that there's also a _right_ adjoint – because the forgetful functor can also be thought of as $k \otimes_k (-)$.

Comment: Is the tensor-hom adjunction a category theory generalization of the principle "$\text{Functions}(X \times Y) = \text{Functions}(X) \otimes \text{Functions}(Y)$"?

Comment: Hmmm. Not quite. Rather, there is a natural bijection between (homo)morphisms $A \otimes B \to C$ and (homo)morphisms $A \to \textrm{Hom}(B, C)$. This is very nearly the definition of the tensor product!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're working over the field $k$, I think the functor $k \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} -: \mathbf{Ab} \to \mathbf{Vect}_k$ should work.

Let $F$ be the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Vect}_k \to \mathbf{Ab}$, $A$ an abelian group and $V$ a vector space over $k$. Then, given $f: A \to F(V)$, define $f': k \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A \to V$ by setting $f'(s \otimes a) := s \cdot f(a)$ and extending additively. Given $g: k \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A \to V$, define $g^*:A \to F(V)$ by setting $g^*(a) := g(1 \otimes a)$. One can check that the assignments $f \mapsto f'$ and $g \mapsto g^*$ are mutually inverse and thus give bijections between $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(A,F(V))$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Vect}_k}(k \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A,V)$.